# How to show percent labels on histogram bars using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have seen lots of question regarding converting count on y axis into percent but must of them are in bar plot.

I want to do similar thing in histogram but not able to show the labels on the bar clearly. Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
x = runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)
data1 <- data.frame(x = x)

ggplot(aes(x = x), data = data1)+
geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), bins = 10, breaks = 
seq(0,10,1), fill = "blue", col = "black")+
geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
            label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
        stat = "count", vjust = -10)+ 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scale_y_continous` with breaks and labels will solve your problem.

```
  data1 <- data.frame (x = runif(100, min = 0, max = 10))
ggplot(aes(x=x), data1) + stat_bin(aes(y = ..count..)) 
ggplot(data1, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram(fill = "blue", col = "black")+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,1),labels = paste(seq(0, 10, by = 1) / 100, "%", sep = ""))+geom_text(aes(y = (..count..),label =  scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="bin",colour="green",vjust=2)
```

or, you can specify where you would like to add the percentage like this:

```
geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)+0.5))
```

of course you can change the color as well. from,

```
stat="bin",colour="your prefer color "
```

Also you can change the width of the bins as follows:

```
geom_histogram(fill = "blue", col = "black", binwidth = 0.5)
```

[image]

[image]

[image: heres the graph]

Comment: how to show the percent on the top of each bar individually?

Comment: you can still use your `geom_text` it will works. Just change it slightly: `geom_text(aes(y = (..count..),label =  your code) `

Comment: see the answer. Hope that help you with your problem.

Comment: how to set bins? I set the bin parameter in geom_histogram() but still getitng `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

Comment: The `stat_bins()` is just a warning message for you. Your data to small. So, try a big  data with some values of the bins and see.