# how do i add the values of the lines to the top of the line in ggplot 2

Tags: r

So this is my code

```
estimated_backlog_value <- 
c(1000,830,1440,1160,420,1230,1200,1520,3330,4710,3190)

names <- c("2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016")

avg_sales_per_unit <- c(68,69,89,87,79,80,112,106,106,114,116)

table <- data.frame(names, estimated_backlog_value,avg_sales_per_unit)

p = ggplot(table, aes(names, estimated_backlog_value))+
        geom_bar(fill = ifelse(names != 2016,"green","blue"),
        stat = "identity") +
        xlab("Years") +
        ylab("Backlog value\n($ in millions)") +
        labs(title = "Diverse Railcar Backlog",
            subtitle = "Provides Strong Earnings Visibility") +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.032,name = "Average Sales Price/Unit\n($ in thousands)"))


p <- p + geom_line(aes(x = as.numeric(names), y = avg_sales_per_unit/0.032))

p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = estimated_backlog_value),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), col = ifelse(names != 2016,"black","red"))

p + geom_text(aes(label=avg_sales_per_unit,vjust=-0.5), col = ifelse(names != 2016,"black","red"))
```

How do I make the numbers that correspond to the lines, so 68,69, etc go on top of the line rather than the bar

Thanks
[image: the graph]

Comment: Could you please upload your graph.

Comment: Could you please include a reproducible data set of `table`; use e.g. `dput`.

Comment: yea, I added the data for table

Comment: @theadleb I think what you are looking forward is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482621/how-to-show-percent-labels-on-histogram-bars-using-ggplot2/46483022#46483022

Comment: @theadleb I just add the graph to your question (based on your code) if it is correct. Could you please accept the edit so it will be helpful for people to help you with your question (if it is different from the one I uploaded).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show percent labels on histogram bars using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482621/how-to-show-percent-labels-on-histogram-bars-using-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, `avg_sales_per_unit` labels appear above the `geom_bar` instead of the `geom_line` because you define `y=estimated_backlog_value` in the parent `aes` to be the y-position e.g. `ggplot(table, aes(names, estimated_backlog_value))`

You will have to define the y-position value for the `geom_text` associated with the `geom_line` using `y = avg_sales_per_unit/0.032` value:

```
p + geom_text(aes(y = avg_sales_per_unit/0.032, label=avg_sales_per_unit,vjust=-0.5), col = ifelse(names != 2016,"black","red"))
```

Edited to answer question: you can use `prettyNum` to format numbers, including adding comma separators.  You can implement it in `ggplot2` as follows to format the numerical labels in `geom_text`.

```
p = p + geom_text(aes(label = prettyNum(estimated_backlog_value, big.mark=",")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), col = ifelse(names != 2016,"black","red"))

p + geom_text(aes(y = avg_sales_per_unit/0.032, label = prettyNum(avg_sales_per_unit, big.mark=","), vjust=-0.5), col = ifelse(names != 2016,"black","red"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it worked. By the way, is there a way to add commas to the different values so for example, 1000 would be 1,000?

Comment: You can use `prettyNum` to do so. I updated the answer to illustrate its use in `geom_text` label input.  If you are satisfied, please accept the answer so it can be marked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because geom_text is using the x and y coordinates of the bars instead of those of the line. If you add to geom_text an argument data containing the correct coordinates, you get the text at the places you expect:

```
p + geom_text(data = data.frame(x=names,y=avg_sales_per_unit/0.032),aes(x=x,y=y,label=avg_sales_per_unit,vjust=-0.5), 
col = ifelse(names != 2016,"black","red"))
```